# Quotient ring is a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Prove that the ring $\mathbb R[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$ is a unique factorization domain.

Comment: What do you expect the OP to say? "I checked $x^2$. I checked $x^2-1$. I checked $x^2-y^2$ ..." Or a confession that it is homework and they just don't want to do it? Just assume good faith.

Comment: @ABC Brandon's request is standard practice when a question is posed like this. He *is* acting in good faith (but your response to him does not show very much good faith.) The OP could explain, for example, any line of approach they tried until this point, ideas, failures etc.

Comment: You should get an idea from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244460 which discussed $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$. The same works here.

Comment: Or you could try to show $\mathbb R /(x^2 +1)$ is not an UFD, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg With two variables one can write $x\times x=(1-y)(1+y)$, providing two distinct irreducible factorizations. It is not clear at all whether a similar argument exists for three variables as you claim. Also several comments here conjecture that the ring *is* in fact a UFD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $R=\mathbb R[X,Y,Z]/(X^2+Y^2+Z^2-1)$. Note that $z-1$ is prime in $R$. Show that $R_{z-1}$ is a UFD and then use [Nagata Criterion](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Nagata_Criterion).

Comment: Thanks a lot..could you you tell me where can I get the proof of Nagata Criterion...@YACP

Comment: @sayak See Theorem 15.39 in Pete Clark's [notes](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/integral.pdf).

Comment: What is $R_{z-1}$?