# Prove that $x−1$ and $y−1$ are irreducible in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, irreducible-polynomials

Let $R$ be the ring of polynomial functions on the circle:

$R=\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/I$ with $I = (X^2 +Y^2 − 1)$ and put $x := X + I$, $y := Y + I$ $∈ R$.

We can define the following Norm map:

$N:R\rightarrow R[x]$ by $N(f + gy):=(f + gy)(f − gy)=f^2 − g^2(1− x^2)$

I have to prove the following statements:

- Prove that $x−1$ and $y−1$ are irreducible in $R$

I tried the following using the norm map:

Suppose that $x-1 = ab$ with $a,b \in R$. Then, $x^2-1 = N(x-1) = N(ab) = N(a)N(b)$. Since $N(a)\mid x^2-1$ but $N(a) = x-1$ is impossible, we must have $N(a)=1$ or $N(b)=1$. But the definition of the norm hows that this means $a$ or $b$ is a unit in R. Hence, $x-1$ is irreducible.

- Prove that $(x −1)$ and $(y−1)$ are not prime ideals in $R$ and that $R$ is not a unique factorization domain
- Show that $a=(x + y−1)^2=2(x−1)(y−1)$ are two distinct factorizations of $a$ as a product of irreducible elements (and a unit 2).

For the last statement I found the following:

$(x + y - 1)^2=x^2 + y^2 + 2xy - 2x - 2y + 1=2xy - 2x - 2y + 2 + I$

$2(x-1)(y-1)=2xy - 2x - 2y + 2$

Any help would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably not helpful, but note that 1-point spaces are irreducible and Zariski-closed on the circle :)

Comment: I still need some more help...

Comment: what is the problem text and what are your additional, possible wrong notes to this problem. It seems to me that you mix this up. is this statement about the norm map part of  the problem or is it added by you. Maybe you can clean this up.

Comment: The norm map was given as a hint. It do not necessarily need this to solve those questions.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/244460/424790 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/747610/424790

Comment: I still have some difficulties of getting correct answers... I really would appreciate it if someone could help me with showing me the right answers

Answer (score 2):

This answer amounts to reordering [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/244487/424790) for the sake of the OP.

1. By repeatedly using the reduction $y^2=1-x^2$ in $R$, one sees that every element can be uniquely written as $a(x) + b(x)y$. Thanks to this we may define $$N : R \to \mathbb{R}[z], \qquad a(x)+b(x)y \mapsto a(z)^2 - b(z)^2(1-z^2),$$ which is multiplicative (check it).
2. With 1. one verifies that invertible elements in $R$ are just the non-zero constants. In fact, if $p(x,y)$ is invertible in $R$ then there exists $q(x,y)$ such that $pq=1$. This implies that $N(p)N(q) = N(pq)=1$ in $\mathbb{R}[z]$, which implies that $N(p)$ (and $N(q)$ too) is a non-zero constant. That is, by writing $p(x,y) = a(x) + b(x)y$,
   $$a(z)^2 - b(z)^2(1-z^2) = c \neq 0.$$
   If $b(z) \neq 0$, then the leading coefficient on the left hand side would be $a_n^2 + b_m^2$, where $a_n$, $b_m$ are the leading coefficients of $a$ and $b$. However, since $z$ does not appear on the right-hand side, we should have $a_n^2 + b_m^2 = 0$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $b=0$ and $a(z)^2 = c$ implies that $a(z) = a \in \mathbb{R}$.
3. If by contradiction $x-1$ is reducible, then $x-1 = pq$ and hence $$(z-1)^2 = N(x-1) = N(p)N(q).$$
   Since neither $p$ (nor $q$) is a unit, $\deg(N(p))>0$ in view of point 2., which leaves as only option $N(p) = z-1$. Write again $p = a(x) + b(x)y$ and $$z-1 = a(z)^2-b(z)^2(1-z^2),$$
   which forces $(1-z)\mid a(z)$. Write then $a(z)=d(z)(z-1)$ and plug it into the above equality to find $$d(z)^2(z-1) +b(z)^2(z+1) = 1.$$
   The leading coefficient on the left-hand side is $d_n^2+b_m^2$, where $d_n,b_m$ are the leading coefficients of $d(z)$ and $b(z)$. Since $z$ does not appear on the right-hand side, we should have $d_n^2+b_m^2 =0$, which is a contradiction. The same conclusion can be drawn about $1-y$ by switching the roles of $x$ and $y$ in the argument up to here.
4. Now, if $\langle x-1\rangle$ was a prime ideal, then $R/\langle x-1\rangle$ would have been an integral domain, but $$R/\langle x-1\rangle \cong \mathbb{R}[X,Y]/\langle X^2+Y^2-1,X-1\rangle \cong \mathbb{R}[X,Y]\langle X-1, Y^2 \rangle \cong \mathbb{R}[Y]/\langle Y^2\rangle,$$ which is not ($y^2 = 0$). Analogously for $\langle y-1\rangle$. In particular, if $R$ was an integral domain, then every irreducible element would have been prime ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain#Properties)) and hence $\langle x-1\rangle$ would have been a prime ideal ([see Wikipedia again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element#Definition)), which is not the case.

You already solved the last bullet.

Comment: Thankyou very much. This will help me a lot understanding the material.

Comment: Can you please explain (4) again? I'm don't really get the part with the isomorphisms and the conclusion from that. Thank you :)

Comment: @Julie What exactly does not convince you?

Comment: @EnderWiggins I don't understand how you get to it. And why it can't be true

Comment: @Julie the chain of isomorphisms is pretty standard: the first one is one of the isomorphism theorems for rings (which one depends on the numbering you saw), the second one follows because $\langle X^2+Y^2-1,X-1\rangle = \langle Y^2,X-1\rangle$, the third one you may try to write it down by yourself (it is not difficult at all) and the reason why $R/\langle x-1\rangle$ cannot be an integral domain is because it is isomorphic to a ring ($\mathbb{R}[Y]/\langle Y^2\rangle$) which is not ($y=Y+\langle Y^2\rangle$ therein is a non-zero element such that $y^2 = 0$).