# Show these polynomial rings are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I wish to show $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2 + Y^2 -1)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[T,T^{-1}]$ (where $X,Y,T$ are formal variables in the bigger polynomial rings$.

I have tried to compare the basic properties, e.g. they are both integral domains but they seem to agree. Can I exploit the way $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed somehow? Since I have shown the result is true for $\mathbb{C}$ in place of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}[T, T^{-1}]$ is the localization of a UFD (a PID, even), hence is a UFD.  However, $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2 + Y^2 - 1)$ is not a UFD: the idea is that $X^2 = (1-Y)(1+Y)$ gives two different factorizations.  For details, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244460/ring-of-trigonometric-functions-with-real-coefficients/244487#244487).

The interesting part is that if we work over $\mathbb{C}$, the two corresponding rings $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2 + Y^2 - 1)$ and $\mathbb{C}[T,T^{-1}]$ *are* isomorphic:
$$
\mathbb{C}[T,T^{-1}] \cong \mathbb{C}[T,U]/(TU - 1) \cong \mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2 + Y^2 - 1)
$$
where the last isomorphism sends $T \mapsto X + iY$ and $U \mapsto X - iY$.

Comment: Very nice idea.

Answer (score 6):

If $\xi$ and $\eta$ are the images of $X$ and $Y$ in the quotient ring, then $\xi^2+\eta^2=1$, so you should find two such elements in $\mathbb{R}[T,T^{-1}]$.

An nonzero element in $\mathbb{R}[T,T^{-1}]$ can be uniquely written as $T^mf(T)$, where $m$ is an integer and $f(T)\in\mathbb{R}[T]$ with $f(0)\ne0$. So suppose
$$
(T^mf(T))^2+(T^ng(T))^2=1
$$
Suppose $m\ge0$ and $n\ge0$. Then the leading coefficient of the left-hand side is positive, so the degree has to be zero, which implies $m=n=0$ and $f$ and $g$ constant.

However, the images of $\xi$ and $\eta$ should generate $\mathbb{R}[T,T^{-1}]$: contradiction.

Suppose $m<0$ and, without loss of generality, $m\le n$. Then we get
$$
f(T)^2+T^{2n-2m}g(T)^2=T^{-2m}
$$
Evaluating at $0$, we obtain $f(0)^2=0$ or $f(0)^2+g(0)^2=0$ (according to $n\ne m$ or $n=m$): in both cases it is a contradiction.