# solutions to $(f(x))^2=(g(x))^2(1-x^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

I am trying to show $f=0, g=0$ are the only solutions to $(f(x))^2=(g(x))^2(1-x^2)$ for any $f(x),g(x)\in \Bbb R[X]$, which is from the answer of the question [Ring of trigonometric functions with real coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244460/ring-of-trigonometric-functions-with-real-coefficients).

I tried to expand it and plug values, but I found no way to prove it.

Comment: Does $g^2(1-x^2)$ mean $[g(x)]^2  (1-x^2)$ or $[g(1-x^2)]^2$ ?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I will edit it. @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: Working over $\mathbb{C}$: what can you say about the multiplicities of the roots of $f^2$? Of the right hand-side?

Comment: @D.Thomine sorry, I cannot see it. I know 1 and -1 are roots for $f$

Comment: @xyz In other words, what can you say about the parity of the highest power of $(1-x)$ which can divide LHS? What about the same for the RHS?

Comment: I got it!!!! Thank you very much for your help!@Macavity. $f(x)$ has $(1-x)$ as a factor, let $n$ be the max power of $1-x$ in $f(x)$, therefore $f(x)^2=h(x)^2(x-1)^{2n}=g(x)^2(x-1)(x+1)$. So $g(x)^2(x+1)=h(x)^2(x-1)^{2n-1}$, thus $g(x)$ has a $1-x$ as a factor, so the parity of the power $1-x$ on the left-hand side is odd, while is even in the right-hand side. I am wondering if I got it right.