# Problem with understanding why $\mathbb{C}[x, y] / (x^2 + y^2 - 1)$ is UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring, unique-factorization-domains

Reading this questions [Ring of trigonometric functions with real coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244460/ring-of-trigonometric-functions-with-real-coefficients/244487#244487)
we can see that $\mathbb{C}[x, y] / (x^2 + y^2 - 1)$ is a UFD because it's isomorphic to Laurent polynomial ring which is UFD.
On the one hand we have the following equality
$$
x^2 = x * x  = (1-y)(1+y) 
$$
So if $\mathbb{C}[x, y] / (x^2 + y^2 - 1)$ is a UFD, it must be that
$$
x = u(1+y)
$$
where $u$ is a unit. Also i have found that $x+iy$ and $x-iy$ are units in this ring, but i can't find $u$. It must be $u = c(x+iy)^n(x+iy)^m$ for some $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c \in \mathbb{C^{*}}$ but it seem to me that such $u$ doesn't exist.

Comment: I would first transform everything to the Laurent polynomial ring parameters.

Comment: See the proofs given at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311675/show-that-mathbbcx-y-x2y2-1-is-a-ufd?noredirect=1&lq=1). They are also helpful.

Comment: I think the comments on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4340924/how-to-describe-the-ring-mathbbc-cosx-sinx-as-a-quotient-ring-of-m) are related, especially my comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4340924/how-to-describe-the-ring-mathbbc-cosx-sinx-as-a-quotient-ring-of-m#comment9055290_4340924).

Comment: @ViktorVaughn yes, they are good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an isomorphism $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)\cong\mathbb{C}[T,T^{-1}]$ given by $T^{\pm1}=X\pm iY$. With this identification in mind, we see $X=(T+T^{-1})/2=\frac{1}{2}T^{-1}(T+i)(T-i)$ is not irreducible because the factors $T\pm i$ are not units (though $\frac{1}{2}T^{-1}$ is), and $1\pm Y=\pm\frac{1}{2i}T^{-1}(T\pm i)^2$ (which we find by substituting $T$ into $X$ and $Y$, combining into one fraction, and factoring numerators.)

Thus, $X^2=1-Y^2$ does not tell us $X$ is associate to either of $1\pm Y$ (which it isn't, as we can see by simplifying the quotient $X/(1\pm Y)$ as a rational function of $T$).