# Proof for Unique Factorization Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

> Prove that the quotient ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is a unique factorization domain.

I am trying to prove first it is a principal ideal domain. However I am really stuck on this problem

Comment: Have you tried writing $x=\cos x$, $y=\sin x$? It's only a suggestion, I don't know if it is the right way.

Comment: @ajotatxe: I had not tried that but I am trying to use that substitution and still got nowhere. I am trying to use the idea of adjoining elements for this one

Comment: Solved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/243735/121097).

Answer (score 4):

Show that the ring is isomorphic to the ring of complex trigonometric polynomials $\mathbb{C}[e^{i\theta},e^{-i\theta}]$.  This is a localization of $\mathbb{C}[t]$ so is a PID.